# Search for files (with conditions) in the Google Drive SDK using Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to search for files in the drive with Java, but I'm not sure how to set the conditions. The example given in the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOSvQmQK_HA&feature=player_embedded) is in Python. So, basically here is the method that will retrieve the List of files from the Drive:

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {

        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();
            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                request.setPageToken(null);
            }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
            request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
}
```

Now, they mention [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters) that the File.List method accepts the q parameter. How can I do that? When I try to set the parameter with examples like the given in the video where q = "title contains 'fruit'", it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Is the request.queue() used for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. I think the Google Drive SDK documentation needs to be a little less ambiguous.

```
Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");
```

Comment: Exactly right. What do you mean by "less ambiguous", some specific ways to improve it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think the documents are really specific with some examples for some languages, but vague with others. It took me some time to find this method, and at the end is not only the parameter "q" that I am passing; it's a whole new method that accepts this parameter. Logically, according to the documentation, it would have been files().list("q"). It would be helpful to organize it like the Android API Guide, but for each example. I know that it wouldn't be efficient, but it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Use `setQ` method for Files list request.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.List.html#setQ(java.lang.String)

For examples on how to query for files/folders:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters#examples

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about this documentation. It didn't show up when I tried to Google it :(